# PIC32 having multiple PORTB's "high" at the same time

Tags: pic, c, microchip, mplabx, mplab

I am trying to set a couple of PORTBbits to "high" (1) at the same time
for that I am using the following code:
I am using thePIC32MX695F512H

```
#define MOV1A_IO TRISBbits.TRISB0
#define MOV1A PORTBbits.RB0
#define MOV1B_IO TRISBbits.TRISB1
#define MOV1B PORTBbits.RB1

#define MOV2A_IO TRISBbits.TRISB2
#define MOV2A PORTBbits.RB2
#define MOV2B_IO TRISBbits.TRISB3
#define MOV2B PORTBbits.RB3

#define MOV3A_IO TRISBbits.TRISB10
#define MOV3A PORTBbits.RB10
#define MOV3B_IO TRISBbits.TRISB11
#define MOV3B PORTBbits.RB11

int main(void)
{
    MOV1A_IO = 0x00; //output
    MOV1B_IO = 0x00; //output
    MOV2A_IO = 0x00; //output
    MOV2B_IO = 0x00; //output

    //while(1){
    MOV2B = 0xFF;
    MOV2A = 0xFF;
    MOV1B = 0xFF;
    MOV1A = 0xFF;
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

But what I get is this:

[image]

I would expect all 3 to be "high". Anyone knows what is wrong with the code

Comment: `return 0;` ? Where do you expect t to `return`? Put `while(1);` in the end.

Comment: PORTs are generally used for reading. LAT are used for writing. What happens if you write to the port using LAT - LATBbits.LATB0 = 1 etc...

Comment: Thank you that works!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LATx`: to write to an output pin

Use `PORTx`: to read an input pin

For all PICs with `LATx` registers, all INPUT must be from `PORTx` and all OUTPUT should be to `LATx`, which totally avoids the problem of flipping bits when you write to a single bit of the port.